# Changing my struct to cpp style struct gives me run time error

Tags: c++, constructor, struct

```
    typedef struct
{
    int day;
    int month;
    int year;
} Date;

 typedef struct
{
    int a;
    int s;
} MetaData;

struct A
{
    char arrA[10];
    char arrB[10];
    Date    date;
    A(char * arrA, char *arrB, const Date& date)
    {
        strcpy(this->arrA, arrA);
        strcpy(this->arrB, arrB);
        this->date = date;
    }
    A(const A& a)
    {    
        strcpy(this->arrA, a.arrA);
        strcpy(this->arrB, a.arrB);
        this->date = a.date;     
    }
};
bool operator < (const A & lhs, const A & rhs)
{
    if(strcmp(lhs.arrA, rhs.arrA) == 0)
    {
        if(strcmp(lhs.arrB, lhs.arrB) == 0)
            return false;
        else return strcmp(lhs.arrB, lhs.arrB);
    }
    else
        return strcmp(lhs.arrA, rhs.arrB);
}
 typedef map<A, MetaData> TickerMap;
int main()
{

TickerMap tickerMap;
char x[10], y[10];
Date date;
A a(x, y, date);
MetaData m;
    //tickerMap.insert(make_pair(a, m));
    cout<<"The element is sucessfully inserted"<<endl;
    return 0; 
}
```

Whenever i create a struct with some constructors.It gives me run time error when i insert the object in the map. Can somebody please tell me the exact problem. It will be very helful. When I have normal structs ( C style) there is no problem during insertion.

Error :Run-Time Check Failure #2 - Stack around the variable 'date' was corrupted. (visual Studio)

Comment: Q: What is the run time error???

Comment: Can you edit the question and add information of the run time error displayed.

Comment: The program is breaking in Visual studio only. I ave just tried running in gcc. It is good there..

Comment: Why all the downvotes? This isn't the best code style, but someone porting something from C doesn't have a choice. Within that constraint it's stylistically fine. Anyway we're not supposed to be style critics and the question is perfectly well formed, self-contained, and non-trivial.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`x` and `y` are uninitialized arrays, containing random garbage. In particular, they generally aren't NUL-terminated. When `A`'s constructor `strcpy`s from them, a buffer overrun occurs.

Your program exhibits undefined behavior. To the extent it appears to work with some compilers, it does so purely by accident.